# What is the relationship between the orbit-stabilizer theorem and Lagrange's theorem?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Is Lagrange's theorem used to prove that the length of the orbit times the order of the stabilizer is the order of the group, or is Lagrange's theorem a corollary of the orbit-stabilizer theorem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, Lagrange's theorem is used to prove the orbit-stabilizer theorem, not the other way around. See the following proof from ["Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications"](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20180801.pdf):

[image]

However, if someone could figure out how to prove the orbit-stabilizer theorem without using Lagrange's Theorem, then you could prove Lagrange's Theorem as a corollary of the orbit-stabilizer theorem, as [Tsemo Aristide](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056926/307483) showed.

Comment: See [there](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem), Lagrange's theorem is not needed to prove the orbit-stabilizer lemma, which is a really straightforward result: the bijection is explicit and canonical.

Comment: @C.Falcon But doesn't that proof rely on the existence of $G / \text{Stab}(x)$ as a quotient group, which relies on Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: In all generality, $G/\operatorname{Stab}(x)$ is not a group, since $\operatorname{Stab}(x)$ needs not to be normal in $G$, the map constructed in the linked proof is only a bijection, not a group morphism. Recall that $G/\operatorname{Stab}(x)$ is just a set of equivalence classes and this construction can be done indepently of all results.

Comment: @C.Falcon I see. However, even in that case, you need to know $G/\text{Stab}(x)$ is a partition of $G$ in order to make the equivalence relation, and proving that all of the cosets of a subgroup partition the original group is basically Lagrange's Theorem. There's no way to go from the equation they prove, which is $\text{Orb}(x)=[G : \text{Stab}(x)]$, to the actual theorem, $|\text{Orb}(x)|\cdot |\text{Stab}(x)|=|G|$, without using Lagrange's Theorem somehow.

Comment: The relationship is similar to that of Rolle's Theorem and the Mean Value Theorem. Rolle's Theorem is a special case which is used to prove the more general result.

Comment: @WillR:  The two answers given already seem to contradict each other, and your comment provides resolution; would you like to upgrade it to an answer?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I think my comment only works as a comment on Noble Mushtak's answer. To be clear, if I were to write an answer myself, I would like to write Noble Mushtak's answer, perhaps with my comment included. Thus, my position is that Noble's answer is the best and should be accepted. Tsemo's answer is not really incorrect, it just uses "corollary" in a slightly unconventional sense of the word; it is this terminological ambiguity that my comment clears up.

Comment: @WillR:  Thanks for your prompt, considered response.  I will take it under consideration.

Answer (score 5):

Lagrange is a corollary, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $H$ acts on $G$ by left multiplication, the orbit of $1$ is $H$ so $|H|Or(G/H)=|G|$ where $Or(G/H)$ is the cardinal of the orbit space.

Comment: Applying the orbit-stabilizer theorem to the action of $H$ on $G$ would only tell you that $|H|=\left|H/St(1)\right|$. It wouldn't give you any information on $G$ since the action of $H$ on itself does not depend on any embedding of $H$ into any group.

Comment: so lagrange is a corollary because Or(G/H) = [G:H] ? if so then how do you know Or(G/H) = [G:H]? if not then what do you mean?