# Questioning the relationship between the orbit-stabilizer theorem and Lagrange's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer

I just learned about the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Some people (such as those in the answers to [this older question about the same topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056919/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem-and-lagranges-the)) seem to argue that Lagrange's theorem is a special case of the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

So, to my understanding, the orbit-stabilizer theorem says this: Each coset of the stabilizer $\mathbf{stab}x$ collects exactly those elements of $G$, which send $x \in X$ to some particular fixed element $x' \in \textbf{orb}x$. Thus, there exists a natural one-to-one correspondence between elements of $\textbf{orb}x$ and the cosets in $G/\textbf{stab}x$:
$$ |\textbf{orb}x| = |G:\textbf{stab}x|. $$

Now I do not see how this would imply Lagrange's theorem. If I take $H \leq G$ acting on $G$ by left multiplication, I do get $\textbf{orb}g = Hg$. As for the stabilizer, we know that $\textbf{stab}g = \{e\}$, for all $g \in G$. Substituting into the equation above, we get a rather obvious fact:
$$ |Hg| = |H:\{e\}| = |H|. $$

The orbit stabilizer theorem does not seem to tell us anything about the size of the set $X$ being acted upon. Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding something here? Are those people conflating the orbit-stabilizer theorem with just any fact having to do with orbits?

Comment: $X$ (in your case, $G$) is always a disjoint union of the orbits.  So, this, coupled with the fact that all orbits have the same size (namely $|H|$), gives Lagrange.

Comment: Note that the disjointness of the orbits/cosets does in fact give you information about the size of the set being acted upon, especially when you know the sizes of all the orbits.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I do realize. But this does not really use the orbit-stabilizer theorem does it?

Comment: Yes, it does.  It is a special case of the theorem, as you point out yourself:  $|Hg|=|H:\{e\}|$.  You can certainly prove it from scratch using only coset information, and that's how most people teach it.  But it is a good motivator for understanding/believing in the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: So the orbit-stabilizer theorem relates to Lagrange's theorem in that it can be used to prove that all cosets are the same size?

Comment: Correct.  Couple that with the disjointness of orbits/cosets and you've got the theorem.

Comment: In that case, that is the answer to my question. Thanks a lot for clarifying this to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The action that gives you Lagrange's theorem is not the action of $H$ on $G$ but the action of $G$ on $G/H$ (by left multiplication). For this action there is one orbit of size $|G/H|$ and the stabilizer (at $[e]$) is $H$. Applying the orbit-stabilizer theorem gives

$$|G/H| = [G : H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$$

which is exactly Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Ah makes sense, probably should have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: "the stabilizer (at $[e]$)": isn't the stabilizer at $H$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. By $[e]$ I mean the image of $e \in G$ under the projection $G \to G/H$. Maybe $eH$ would have been less ambiguous.